# Jmeter not working correctly with Junit (Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory)

Tags: junit, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to do some cost testing using JMeter, however my plan is to use the our current API unit test suite as the cost test plan, as many of the tests simulate user flows. That being said, I am running into some issues with JMeter. I have the jar with the unit tests in the /lib/junit folder as I should, however when I launch JMeter, the edit tab has no items (on mac, from my research this issue yields a greyed out edit button on windows), I cannot right click on any of the objects and the JUnit Samplers do not appear in the test plan. Here is the data from the logs:

```
2016/07/08 13:51:33 WARN  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Missing jar? Could not create kg.apc.jmeter.config.redis.RedisDataSet. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool$Config 
2016/07/08 13:51:33 INFO  - jmeter.util.BSFTestElement: Registering JMeter version of JavaScript engine as work-round for BSF-22 
2016/07/08 13:51:33 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/07/08 13:51:33 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/07/08 13:51:33 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/07/08 13:51:33 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/07/08 13:51:33 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2016/07/08 13:51:33 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser 
2016/07/08 13:51:33 INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'keytool' 
2016/07/08 13:51:33 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file /Users/tester/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin/proxyserver.jks 
2016/07/08 13:51:34 WARN  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Could not instantiate org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JUnitTestSamplerGui java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.isChildOf(ClassFinder.java:377)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.access$000(ClassFinder.java:47)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder$ExtendsClassFilter.accept(ClassFinder.java:92)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesInOnePath(ClassFinder.java:441)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClasses(ClassFinder.java:289)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesThatExtend(ClassFinder.java:264)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesThatExtend(ClassFinder.java:196)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesThatExtend(ClassFinder.java:178)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesThatExtend(ClassFinder.java:140)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JUnitTestSamplerGui.setupClasslist(JUnitTestSamplerGui.java:181)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JUnitTestSamplerGui.createClassPanel(JUnitTestSamplerGui.java:212)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JUnitTestSamplerGui.init(JUnitTestSamplerGui.java:167)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JUnitTestSamplerGui.<init>(JUnitTestSamplerGui.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.initializeMenus(MenuFactory.java:492)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.<clinit>(MenuFactory.java:160)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui.createPopupMenu(TestPlanGui.java:93)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:156)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.EditCommand.doAction(EditCommand.java:47)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:62)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

2016/07/08 13:51:34 ERROR - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory:  java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.isChildOf(ClassFinder.java:377)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.access$000(ClassFinder.java:47)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder$ExtendsClassFilter.accept(ClassFinder.java:92)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesInOnePath(ClassFinder.java:441)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClasses(ClassFinder.java:289)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesThatExtend(ClassFinder.java:264)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesThatExtend(ClassFinder.java:196)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesThatExtend(ClassFinder.java:178)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesThatExtend(ClassFinder.java:140)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JUnitTestSamplerGui.setupClasslist(JUnitTestSamplerGui.java:181)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JUnitTestSamplerGui.createClassPanel(JUnitTestSamplerGui.java:212)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JUnitTestSamplerGui.init(JUnitTestSamplerGui.java:167)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JUnitTestSamplerGui.<init>(JUnitTestSamplerGui.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.initializeMenus(MenuFactory.java:492)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.<clinit>(MenuFactory.java:160)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui.createPopupMenu(TestPlanGui.java:93)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:156)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.EditCommand.doAction(EditCommand.java:47)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:62)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

2016/07/08 13:51:34 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception:  java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.isChildOf(ClassFinder.java:377)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.access$000(ClassFinder.java:47)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder$ExtendsClassFilter.accept(ClassFinder.java:92)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesInOnePath(ClassFinder.java:441)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClasses(ClassFinder.java:289)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesThatExtend(ClassFinder.java:264)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesThatExtend(ClassFinder.java:196)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesThatExtend(ClassFinder.java:178)
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesThatExtend(ClassFinder.java:140)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JUnitTestSamplerGui.setupClasslist(JUnitTestSamplerGui.java:181)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JUnitTestSamplerGui.createClassPanel(JUnitTestSamplerGui.java:212)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JUnitTestSamplerGui.init(JUnitTestSamplerGui.java:167)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JUnitTestSamplerGui.<init>(JUnitTestSamplerGui.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.initializeMenus(MenuFactory.java:492)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.<clinit>(MenuFactory.java:160)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui.createPopupMenu(TestPlanGui.java:93)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:156)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.EditCommand.doAction(EditCommand.java:47)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:62)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

2016/07/08 13:51:35 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui.createPopupMenu(TestPlanGui.java:93)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:156)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.EditCommand.doAction(EditCommand.java:47)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:62)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I have been doing some research all day and so far no solutions have helped. So that no one wastes their time, results like [this](https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/jmeter-could-not-initialize-menufactory-class/) and really all of the google search results from various stack trace errors in this log have yielded no viable results. I am using Jmeter 3 but have tried it with jmeter 2.12 and jmeter 2.9. This may or may not be relevant, but Jmeter 2.12 works in the sense that this error does not occur, however none of the unit tests appear in the sampler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it everyone however it doesn't really explain why those were the errors in the stack trace. The unit tests require credentials which as it turns out I had to place in the Jmeter /bin folder. Once I did this, the tests ran fine. Again, I am not sure why this caused the errors that it caused.

Answer (score 3):

The first line explains everything:

> **Missing jar?**
>
> Could not create kg.apc.jmeter.config.redis.RedisDataSet. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool$Config

This is due to missing [Apache Pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/) jars in JMeter classpath.

It looks like your test is created somewhere with [Redis](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/) plugin installed and you're currently trying to run it on a clean JMeter.

I would recommend the following:

1. Get "clean" JMeter 3.0
2. [Install JMeter Plugin Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)
3. With the Plugin Manager install Redis Data Set
4. Import your test libraries into "lib/junit" folder
5. Restart JMeter

Comment: that was my first thought too. I have tried those steps and it didn't work. Furthermore, JMeter works fine when I use the test junit jar it comes with, and other jars with unit tests. I think perhaps something in my jar could be hijacking it or not allowing the GenericObject to be found.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you :

- install a clean 3.0 version
- add your dependencies in jmeter/lib
- your junit classes in lib/junit
- if using junit 4, ensure You tick Search for JUnit4 annotations box in your JUnit Request Sampler

No need for your case to install Jmeter plugins nor plugin manager.

If issue persists show your new jmeter.log file